# Surface Pro 4 - Half of my screen Flickers / Shakes

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-surface

Currently I have this issue:

I bought the Surface Pro 4 a month ago. It was doing fine. Then for some reason 3 days ago, half of my screen either flicks or shakes uncontrollably.

I have contacted Microsoft support to help, even to the extent of doing a factory reset and re-updating it.

My last resort would be a warranty repair. Since I am in no condition to do that for the time being, I would prefer to repair it firsthand, first.

Does anyone of you have any solution?

I have tried :

- Disabling Hyper-V
- Hard Reset and fully re-update.
- Have the latest firmware.

I have filter out the conditions :

1. Detached magnetized accessories (The Pen, Charger, Keyboard) - Seems to be able to stop the flickering.
2. It will only flicker when doing something. (Even touching the screen)

If made one video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cjXUFevCT18) and an other [here](http://youtube.com/watch?v=jIysPBI74R0), where you can see that problem.

**Update:**

Now the texts and whatever that flickers are burnt , as in now it is fixed there.. and the pixels are all doubled. As you can see below!
[image]

Comment: This problem is not fixable. There is a whole website dedicated to it https://flickergate.com and a forum thread on Microsoft's official forum

Comment: answers.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/forum/surfpro4-surfdrivers/surface-pro-4-screen-flickering-shacking/570165cb-50a0-4d71-bcb1-310ddd869d1d

Answer (score 3):

### Maybe caused by hardware

It looks like a that your gpu (intel hd graphics) is going to conk out! If this is the case, then its a hardware problem and the microsoft support or any other technical workshop would be the last hope for your surface.

*I had the a similar problem with my notebook. It was a hardware issue and the only thing that I could do was it to send to the manufacturer support. He told me the same as I told above, and it was true.*

---

### Or is it just a bug?

**Below are maybe some interesting article:**

- [Microsoft issues fix for Surface Book, Surface Pro 4 screen flicker](http://www.cnet.com/news/microsoft-fixes-surface-book-surface-pro-4-screen-flicker/)
- [Surface Book, Surface Pro 4 screen flicker? Now Microsoft updates Windows 10 flagships' firmware](http://www.zdnet.com/article/surface-book-surface-pro-4-screen-flicker-now-microsoft-updates-windows-10-flagships-firmware/)
- [The issue is logged here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/forum/surfpro4-surfdrivers/surface-pro-4-noticeable-backlight-flicker/9913f2d3-295f-4a38-93f4-892c84df8b57?auth=1)
- [Surface Pro 4 And Surface Book Suffering From Ugly Screen Flickering Issues: Here’s How To Fix It](http://www.techtimes.com/articles/100352/20151028/surface-pro-4-and-surface-book-suffering-from-ugly-screen-flickering-issues-here-s-how-to-fix-it.htm)

**After a small google search folling possibilities to troubleshoot this issue:**

- One article above say that this issue is caused by when the Hyper-V role got installed. They say a deinstallation of Hyper-V from your Surface shoud fix this problem.
- In other article I read that this issue is caused after a bad update of the intel hd graphics drives. Get the old driver version back or what until microsfot fix this bug!

Comment: cant be the gpu though.. its new

Comment: @MohdNasrulIwanFajaruddin It can always be the gpu. Even when new. There's a reason warranties exist, and it's because even manufacturers mess up.

Comment: microsofts will be going to replace mine if this continues.. one more last step.. i have been with their tech for the past 2 days..

Comment: After all they've done , it seems the flickers returned this morning.

So i had an idea of testing the room temperature with the device , as how it will react to cold and hot condition.

I went outside of my server cave with the surface pro 4, to the poolside of my house direct under the sunlight , it returned to normal by minutes.

i guess , cave was too cold.

Comment: FWIW, disabling the Hyper-V did *not* fix this for me. I'm still looking for a solution.

@Stackcraft_noob: You mention getting the old driver version. Do you have a reference to which one works?

Comment: @logidelic I can't solve your problem from only one comment. I don't know what device you have neither what software you are running? My recommenditation is: keep all drivers allways updated. After I installed the latest updateds on my computer this bug got fixed. If you want to try it with older drivers: After a small google search I found this-> https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/81503/Intel-HD-Graphics-for-Previous-Generation-Intel-Processors

Comment: Those drivers actually will not install on the Surface Pro 4. In any case, it was/is a (very common) hardware issue. I actually have a bunch of tablets (for work) and two of them (out of ~10 suffered from the problem). I got MS to replace those 2 and the new ones are just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem for some time now. I tried a few of the solutions, but none of them worked. I'm writing this for anyone else in case it might work for them. I've found that the flickering stops if there is any movement on the screen: mouse moves, video playing, page tab loading. In order to stop it happening to me, rather than solve the underlying hardware/software issue, I simply turned on the seconds in the taskbar clock. This means that there is always movement on the screen, thus circumventing the shaking/flickering from starting.

A guide to how to add the seconds to the clock can be found here:
http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/show-seconds-taskbar-clock-showsecondsinsystemclock/

Hope it works for you, it gave me no end of headaches!

Answer (score -1):

it seems like the temperature of my screen seems to affect the shaking, its extremely cold where I live and then I warm it up with some skyrim and it seemed to do the trick within a minute